# How to get user location in Angular Universal (SSR)?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I want to get the user location in angular 13 universal. But I can't use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() function beause a universal application doesn't execute in the browser.

How to do it? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can get the user geo-location by using a third-party API on your Angular SSR. It will look up the user IP and will return the location details.

Comment: Prince of Bel Air? Trying to get into programming now? Happy to assist with 1:1 training :P

Comment: Thank you. I solved by using the isPlatformBrowser function of Angular.